# system - softnet_stat - Netdata alarm

Tags: linux, netdata

We got this Netdata alarm

> system.softnet_stat number of times, during the last 10min, ksoftirq
>   ran out of sysctl net.core.netdev_budget or
>   net.core.netdev_budget_usecs, with work remaining (this can be a cause
>   for dropped packets)

I have been searching for information on how to resolve this issue. Everyone suggest increasing *netdev_budget* and/or *netdev_budget_usecs*, but many sources contradict each other on how the limits should be set. Some suggest we should increase *netdev_budget* to around 30K events, some to 600 events. Our config */etc/sysctl.conf* has everything commented out, I guess all the values are default?

Our daily average event count is 10K-20K. In *system.softnet_stat* chart we can see that squeezed events exist even when the processed event count is only 2K.

In short, how do we calculate what values should we assign to *netdev_budget* and/or *netdev_budget_usecs*?

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-fits-all answer for this problem. In general, you should set higher values in sysctl.conf until you find something that works; however it is also possible the machine is receiving more packets than it can handle, so there may be no values that would work.
Based on https://github.com/netdata/netdata/issues/1076 and https://nateware.com/2013/04/06/linux-network-tuning-for-2013/ here is a sample config that users have reported to work:

```
# /etc/sysctl.d/99-network-tuning.conf

# http://www.nateware.com/linux-network-tuning-for-2013.html
# Increase Linux autotuning TCP buffer limits
# Set max to 16MB for 1GE and 32M (33554432) or 54M (56623104) for 10GE
# Don't set tcp_mem itself! Let the kernel scale it based on RAM.
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.core.rmem_default = 16777216
net.core.wmem_default = 16777216
net.core.optmem_max = 40960

# cloudflare uses this for balancing latency and throughput
# https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-story-of-one-latency-spike/
## net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 1048576 2097152
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 5242880 33554432

net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216

# Also increase the max packet backlog
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 100000
## net.core.netdev_budget = 50000
net.core.netdev_budget = 60000
net.core.netdev_budget_usecs = 6000

# Make room for more TIME_WAIT sockets due to more clients,
# and allow them to be reused if we run out of sockets
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 30000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 2000000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 10

# Disable TCP slow start on idle connections
net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle = 0

# If your servers talk UDP, also up these limits
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 8192
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 8192
```